# Trying to create a function to transform list of strings into 1 string and add spaces between words

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec createSentence(list) = (

    match list with
      case [] -> failwith "błędna lista"
      | case [_] -> List.hd list
      | case [_,_] -> List.hd list ^ createSentence(List.tl list)        
      | case _ -> List.hd list ^ " " ^ createSentence(List.tl list);; 
      
  );;
```

Ocaml returns a Syntax error: operator expected. I have no idea how to move forward with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern-matching in OCaml has the following syntax,

```
match <expr> with
| <pattern1> -> <action1>
| <pattern2> -> <action2>
...
```

e.g.,

```
match ["hello"; "world"] with
| [word1; word2] -> print_endline (word1 ^ word2)
| _ -> assert false
```

Also, note that the list elements in OCaml are separated with `;`

I would suggest reading the [Introduction to OCaml](https://ocaml.org/manual/coreexamples.html) or some [OCaml book](https://ocaml.org/learn/books.html)

Update: to make it more clear, there is no `case` keyword in OCaml and you shouldn't write `case` before a pattern, i.e., instead of `| case []`, just write `| []`.

Comment: I understand the pattern matching syntax and I'm trying to return head of the list  concatenated with spaces and the rest of the list as the action. What am I missing?

Comment: there is no `case` keyword in OCaml and there is no need to write `case []`, just do `| []` without the `case` word.

Comment: I see. I am basing this program on a Scala one with the same functionality and I didn't even notice because of fatigue. I am really sorry for wasting your time and thank you a lot for help!

Comment: No worries, it happens to all of us, especially when switching languages)